# webserver problem

Tags: webserver, vps

I have a web serwer on VPS.

My website isn't working. In the log files I found these two erors

> [Wed Jan 09 06:25:01.902230 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25757] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
>   [Wed Jan 09 06:25:01.953796 2019] [so:warn] [pid 25757] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping

How to solve them?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Those two lines don't indicate any error at all. They're just informational logs. Can you share a bit more info about your setup? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1108596/edit) your question and add relevant `apache` configuration and the specific error you get trying to open the website. Try looking in `access.log`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declare the module php7_module twice, search the duplicated line, remove one of them and this will fix the issue.